# angular serialize form versus model

Tags: angularjs, serialization

If I serialize my form, I'll be sending way too much redundant data back to the server. I only want to send back certain fields.

Say the user needs a lot of information about a package to make the decision whether or not to submit it for delivery. They need name, date, city, country, etc. These are all properties of this package, and so are part of this item in the Packages object array - and thus are in the model too.

But I only need to put back one or two bits of data - say, 'weight' and 'selected'. It is silly to submit the entire model of the package, since it contains a whole bunch of terms that the server doesn't need.

Can I serialize just the editable data?

I've been reading up on angular serialization but no one seems to have encountered this scenario. (I'm, sure they have, I'm just searching the wrong term or solution)

Comment: The concept you are looking for is DTO (Data Transfer Object).  there are multiple ways to construct DTOs that only contain the data you need on the server or client.

Comment: You might be referring to a `Dto`: which would be a light-weight object for sending only relevent data across network.

Comment: @Claies that is exactly what they're inquiring about. Should they bother making a wrapper to send as the DTO or should they just use the default serialized JSON to send, even though it's loaded with non-pertinent data.

Comment: I'd say, unless you're app has a complex data structure or is going to be a high-volume site with thousands of simultaneous requests, you could probably send the whole object with negligible performance impact.

Comment: That seems ugly. Surely I'm not the first person to want to send a subset of data from a form. And surely I won't be massaging the data every time.

Comment: If I were to remove the name attribute from the fields I don't need returned, they shouldn't get submitted, right? I'm not sure if serialize respects the name attribute.